# Transform Javascript code to JSON and vice versa

Tags: javascript, json, dojo, dgrid

I'm working on a small project in which I will work with dgrid dojo, the dgrid must be customized according to the profile of the person if he's administrator or simple user. 
The dgrid will be filled from a REST service, and I had the idea to not only fill the dgrid but also customize it with textbox, buttons and checkbox.

For example here is the code of a dgrid with 2 columns whose fields can not be changed:

```
window.Grid= new StandardGrid({
    sort: "abbreviation",
    store: stateStore(),
    columns: {
           abbreviation: 'Abbreviation',
           name: 'Name'
    }
}, "MyGrid");
```

the service must verify if the person is an administrator and if so send in JSON Format the settings to add more features to dgrid, by changing "columns" with :

```
[ editor({
    label: "Abbreviation",
    field: "abbreviation",
    editor: "text",
    editOn: "dblclick"
}),
editor({
    label: "Name",
    field: "name",
    editor: "text",
    editOn: "dblclick"
})]
```

I want to send this configuration code in json format.
I want to know if this is workable and if so, how?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since functions aren't a valid part of JSON, you'd need to do some amount of processing to go between JSON and dgrid column plugins.  For example, in the case of `editor`, you could just test each object for presence of the `editor` property, and if found, apply the `editor` function around it when you actually create the column structure from your JSON.

Comment: I thought for this solution but I wonder if there will be no worries security side in so doing ?

Comment: There shouldn't be any more risk than without invoking a column plugin.  So long as you're still using `JSON.parse` up-front of course (which `dojo/request` with `handleAs: 'json'` will try to do if possible, via `dojo/json`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure regarding Dojo. But if you want to convert a JS Object to JSON then simply:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(objectGoesHere);
```

Comment: I presume the question is more focused around the fact that functions aren't a thing in JSON.

Comment: I believe that the parameterization of the grid is not an object