# How to call dojo function on JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, dojo, dgrid

I am currently working on a project in `DOJO` and struck at this point.

I am using dgrid in dojo to generate table and I need to have checkbox in the first column.

[Here is Code](http://jsfiddle.net/nduHh/14/light/) that is working fine but my requirement is different.

I am taking values for headers and data from a `JSON` file

**Here is the Json file ABC.JSON :**

```
{
"properties": {
    "dataLoading": "full",
    "classNames": ["abc"],
    "autoRefresh": 60,
    "sort" : [ {"attribute":"raiseTime", "decending":true} ]
},
"columns": [
    [[

        { "field":"abc","label":"my label","sortable":true },
        { "field":"def","label":"second label","sortable":true }
    ]],
    [[
        { "field":"fgh", "label":"third label","sortable":true },
        { "field":"ijk", "label":"fourth label","sortable":true }
]]]
```

}

**But to have checkbox feature in table we should have :**

```
var grid = new SelectionGrid({
    columns: [
        selector({ label: '' }),
        { field: 'firstName', label: 'First Name', sortable: false },
        { field: 'lastName', label: 'Last Name', sortable: false }
    ],
    selectionMode: 'none'
}, 'grid');
```

So, In my `JSON` I need to call `selector()` on label. How can I do that in `JSON` ? Is there any way?

Comment: you can call selector() function in formatter property of Dojo column config. you need to pass the name of JS function in formatter property. like in the code below.
{ field: 'firstName', label: 'First Name', sortable: false formatter:selector},

Comment: Its not working @Arun

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transform Javascript code to JSON and vice versa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265557/transform-javascript-code-to-json-and-vice-versa)

Comment: As explained by Ken's link above, you need to process the json after it has been received from the server. For example, something like this http://jsfiddle.net/b40d40t0/ ?

Comment: Try this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22428307/dojo-datagrid-dgrid-adding-checkbox-column